# pdo call to fill variables to use later

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, svg, pdo

Trying to get info from a database based on a click event and load the data into variables to be used later in the form. This is part of the code. A connection to reps table has been made using PDO::

```
function fill_contact(evt) //display click event
    {
        var country_id = evt.target.id
        document.getElementById('country_name').firstChild.data = country_id

        <?php 
   $country = $_GET['country_name'];
   try {
   // Establish server connection and select database
   $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $password);
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   } catch(PDOException $e){
   die("Sorry, we could not connect you to this database, please contact the Administrator to sort this out.". $e->getMessage());/** try open contact form here**/
   }
   /** run prepare to select records **/    
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, email, photo FROM reps WHERE country = :country");
   $stmt->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $stmt->execute();
   ?>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function fill_contact(evt) //display click event
  {
    var country_id = evt.target.id
    document.getElementById('country_name').firstChild.data = country_id
    /* need to get a ajax http fetch statement here???*/
  }

    function getDataFile(mapString , useData) 
    {
    /** call getURL() if available **/
    if (window.getURL) {
    getURL(mapString , useData);
    }
    else
    /** call XMLHttpRequest() if available **/
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        function XMLHttpRequestCallback() 
        {
        if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4) {        useData({success:xmlRequest.status,content:xmlRequest.responseText,contentType:xmlRequest.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")})
        }
        }
     var xmlRequest = null;
        xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlRequest.open("GET",mapString,true);
        xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = XMLHttpRequestCallback;
        xmlRequest.send(null);
        }
    /** write an error message if either method is not available **/
    else {
    alert("your browser/svg viewer neither supports window.getURL nor window.XMLHttpRequest!");
    }  
    }
 </script>

<body>
 <div id="IndexPage_Left_top">
            <h1>Country: <span class="label" id="country_name"> </span>  </h1>
            <table >
                <tbody>                    
                  <tr>
                  <td><h4>Regional Representative: </h4></td>
                  <td><h4><span class="label" id="firstname">$firtname</span> <span class="label" id="lastname">$lastname</span></h4></td><!--get Rep name from database based on country from svg to display-->
                  </tr>
                  <tr></tr>
                  <tr height="300px" align="top">
                  <td ><h4> Photo:</h4></td><!--get Rep photo from database based on country from svg to display-->
                  <td><span class="photo" id="photo"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td><input style='margin-top: 20px;' type="submit" value="Contact me" id='jqxButton' /></td>
                  </tr><!-- if clicked, it opens a contact form below, the email address is hidden-->

                </tbody>
            </table>    
        </div>
        <div id="IndexPage_Left_bottom">
        <h4>email form here<h4>
        <p> email address is <span class="label" id="email">$email</span> </p><!-- if email is clicked, it opens a contact form here with email address from above -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="IndexPage_Right">

 <svg id="map" version="1.1"    rest of svg code
```

This goes with my other question about svg. ([displaying data from sql from clicking on svg map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714789/displaying-data-from-sql-from-clicking-on-svg-map)) Once i click on a svg, it populates variables used to display data about country clicked. The variables are also used to populate a contact form.

It does not want to populate the table?

Comment: Did you test you web service for correct output as expected.

Comment: hey there. You should definitely copy/paste the exact error here (even if it seems a simple syntax error to you.) Also, you mention your other question? what other question? Could you add a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

You have error in PHP code

Change your code `$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM reps WHERE 'country_id' = :country');`

To

```
  $query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM reps WHERE country_id = :country');
```

Comment: changed the code as you said. Still getting syntax error. I might be a bit slow, been programming for 3 months now. baby step plse.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is in those lines, this is how they should look:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM reps WHERE country = :country_id');
$query->bindValue(':country_id', $country, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

on one end, the parameter was named `country_id`, yet you binded the value to the parameter `country`. PDO is great, but it can't yet do telepathy.

I downright prefer to use positional parameters, removing all this error-prone hand-writing:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM reps WHERE country = ?');
$query->execute(array($country));
```

you can always pass an array to the `execute()` method with the values to be binded. With positional parameters, the array must be a 0-indexed array containing the values *matching the order in your query*. You can also do it with named parameters, with no need to match the order:

```
$query->execute(array(':country_id'=>$country));
```

Be aware that you can't mix the two, ever. If you prepare your query with named parameters, they must all be named parameters, and binded as such, if you use positional placeholders, they must all be positional placeholders, and be binded as such.

Comment: my pleasure. Also, I'm just now noticing you are still using `mysql_*`. I,d suggest you read [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). As a matter of fact, I'd be really surprised if the code posted in your question runs at all as there seems to be some syntax errors. If I can make yet another suggestion to help in your learning, make a habit of adding `ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of each of your php scripts. It might really help you

Comment: I used your suggestion and read a whole lot more. I finally got it working :) The problem is now to write (learn how) to use XMLHttpRequest and use the data from the database in the click event. my code is now